# SharePoint TaxonomyFieldControl can not render the Taxonomy Picker?

Tags: sharepoint

I add a `TaxonomyFieldControl` to a page layout. but the control can not render the taxonomy picker instead of just rending the field name related to the control.

the interesting thing is: if i edit the properties in edit form, it works well.

Comment: Where are you adding the control? Are you doing this in the code behind? The aspx layout page?

Comment: yes. i add <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="c6027859-c15e-464f-8485-c7f0aa6f1219" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl> in layout aspx page.   and it just render "category.Theme" the field name associated to the TaxonomyFieldControl. and you could see the screenshot at http://www.facebook.com/groups/sharepointarchitectforum/

Comment: A link to a private Facebook group? haha, surprising

Comment: i am a member for sharepoint architect facebook group. i post the error screen on it. :>

Comment: Well, nobody else can see the page unless they're already in the group. Maybe you can put a link to the image you're seeing? I know Facebook doesn't have that much privacy/security for the pictures they host. Or just upload it here on StackOverflow.

Comment: ha ha i am new born in stackoverflow. i am limited to upload images.. :>

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add a reference to the assembly where the taxonomy picker control is to the page layout, like:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

[Check this link for more details.](http://blog.degree.no/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-adding-taxonomyfieldcontrol-to-custom-page-layout/)

Comment: i add the register string in the top of page. but it still not work. because if i do not add the register string, the page will occurs error. but this time, there are not any error. and just render the field name. how poor i am to face to strange issue....

Comment: Dear Kache, i check the ULS log and search "Error","Warning" and nothing found...

Answer (score 0):

This OOB user control is buggy and useless.

Rename TaxonomyPicker.ascx to something like TaxonomyPicker.ascx.buggy. The location of the file is:

%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\TaxonomyPicker.ascx

You can either do this manually or use PowerShell.

```
$taxonomyPicker = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\TaxonomyPicker.ascx"
If (Test-Path $taxonomyPicker)
{
   Move-Item -Path $taxonomyPicker -Destination $taxonomyPicker".buggy" -Force
}
```